# Extracting highways from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, extract, osmosis

I am trying to extract all highway types for the world from OSM through Osmosis. My Osmosis command looks like below, however, after the extract, I find certain roads (especially, motorways and trunk types) are missing when I compare with the results against overpass-turbo. The output from overpass-turbo is complete for a region while what I get from the extract isn't.

```
osmosis --read-xml file=file/path --tf accept-ways highway=* --used-node --write-pgsql host="<host>" database="osm" user="<user>" password='<pw>'
```

Update:

This is how the overpass results (orange) and extracts I did (blue) for Boston seaport area look like. Results from overpass has everything in my extract and more as you can find in the image.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Actually, the problem was discovered to be a filter that is set to extract only street segments that has a name tag. Therefore, the issue is not related to osmosis or the source OSM data.

Comment: what are the tags in OSM for the roads are missing in osmosis but present in overpass-turbo? Are they highway = ...?

Comment: All tag types are present. Meaning, all highway types like, motorway, trunk etc are there but the completeness is the issue. Several major motorways I see on overpass cannot be seen in my extract.